# CKEditor 4 Freezing

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

Using Ckeditor 4 is there a way to solve the Editor freezes and pasting the contents multiple times ?

Comment: Your question is very generic. Try adding more of what the issue is when this happens and what did you try to fix it?

Comment: While using ckeditor 4, it randomly pasting contents mutiple times and webpage is freezing. It occurs randomly .For these things, I need to close and reopen the tabs